# "Official" docker backup strategy - what about consistency?

Tags: backup, docker, consistency

The [suggested strategy](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) to manage and backup data in docker looks something like this:

```
docker run --name mysqldata -v /var/lib/mysql busybox true
docker run --name mysql --volumes-from mysqldata mysql
docker run --volumes-from mysqldata -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/mysql
```

However, when I backup running containers that way, I won't get a consistent backup, would I?
I'm aware of tools like `mysqldump`, but what if I need to backup, for example, a folder to which files are constantly added and removed?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem you are facing, i.e. backing up changing files is independent of docker. Use a tool such as [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/) or [dirvish](http://www.dirvish.org/) to make backups into a volume and then use the approach you mentioned above to move those backups to somewhere safer like Amazon s3 or glacier based on your reliability requirement.

Whether you mount volumes from another container or the host vm using the -v switch the changes to the files are reflected in all containers (or host vm) in more or less real-time. (There is some delay because of the AUFS that docker uses on top of host fs, but its not huge). If the backup container was running perpetually it could keep taking backups and the files would always reflect latest files seen by the mysql container.

Edit: For clarity.

Comment: _"to make backups into a volume"_ But these backups won't be consistent then, right?
What I mean: You basically can't do consistent backups inside a container. You have to snapshot (lvm/btrfs) /var/lib/docker/volumes/XYZ and back it up on the host machine.

Comment: Volumes are shared between running containers in real(ish)-time. You can even mount them from host file system. using the -v /host_fs/location:/container_fs/location. All changes to the files in the volume should be available to all containers and host at the same time.

Comment: I'm aware of that. The problem is that I need _consistent_ backups:  snapshot the state of the filesystem _atomically_ at one point in time and backup data from this read-only snapshot. I don't know how to do this inside a container, since I need to use lvm or btrfs-tools to do that. With the approach described above, nobody prevents the filesystem from changing while the backup is taking place.

Comment: In that case you can either switch to one of the other docker fs http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/filesystems/ and then take backups of the entire container external to container. Or use a volume and which mounts to host fs and take backups there. So definitely outside container. You may be able to get lvm inside a container if you used privileged mode.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail, From the link you gave (last paragraph): "A volume is a plain directory from the host mounted into the container, which means it has none of the overhead that the storage backends may have". Which means that we can use all backup tools on host, we don't need to enter into container at all, we can store our host volume directory /var/lib/docker/vfs/ in LVM and use LVM for snapshot. Am i right?

Comment: Yes that should be possible